# sinc function amplitude wrong in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, plot

It seems that pgfplots has a problem with plotting the sinc function, aka sin(x)/x. Why is the amplitude wrong? It should be 1 at x=0. As to my knowledge the y-scale is nonsense (compare http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28x%29%2Fx).

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot [domain = -720:720, samples = 200]
                {sin(x)/x};     
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is calculated purely numerically, unlike Wolfram. Assuming it can't literally calculate 0/0 at x=0, the next point might be at 1440/200=7.2. sin(7.2)/7.2=0.0174, near your plotted answer.

Comment: The PGF `sin` function expects its input in degrees.

Comment: ah, I got it. It must be {sin(x)/ (x*pi/180) }. Then it looks fine!

Comment: Should we close this question then?

Comment: @percusse yes, ok.

Answer (score 7):

This is the problem: While the sinus takes the argument in degree, the denominator must still be in radians:

```
\addplot [domain = -720:720, samples = 200]
            {sin(x)/ (x*pi/180) };
```

leads to how the sinc should be:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `sinc` function is defined by the `\pst-math` module from `pstricks`, and its argument is in `radians`:

```
\documentclass[11pt, pdf, x11names]{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\psset{algebraic=true,dimen=middle,dotstyle=o,dotsize=3pt 0,linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2, arrowinset=0.25, yunit=3,xunit=0.5, xtrigLabels, linecolor=SlateGray3, tickcolor=SlateGray3, ticksize=2.5pt -2.5pt}%
%
\begin{pspicture*}(-14,-0.4)(15,1.4)%\radians
\psplot[linecolor =Tomato3,linewidth = 1.2pt, plotpoints = 500,plotstyle = curve]{-14}{14.5}{ SINC(x)}
\psset{trigLabels, labelFontSize=\footnotesize, dx=\psPi, arrows=->}
\psaxes(0,0)(-14,-0.4)(15,1.4)[$ x $, -120][$ y $, -140]
\uput[dl](0,0){$ O $}
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]